# Is it the pythonic way to use multiple comprehensions in a single return statement?

Tags: python

I am starting with the book "Data Science from Scratch" which is an awesome hands-on text on data science with Python.

One of the examples in the book contains a PERL like one liner.

```
def foaf_ids_bad(user):
    return [foaf["id"]
            for friend in user["friends"]
            for foaf in friend["friends"]]
```

I would like to understand whether re-writing the above code as follows is considered as python convention? or the above one is more pythonic way

```
def friends_of_friend_ids_bad(user):
    foaf_list = list()
    for friend in user['friends']:
        for foaf in friend['friends']:
            foaf_list.append(foaf['id'])
    return foaf_list
```

Comment: List comprehensions tend to be considered more "Pythonic"

Comment: Also remember that Python cares about correct indentation, which your second code snippet doesnt have

Comment: List comprehension is usually considered more Pythonic.

Comment: List comprehensions(LC) tend to be pythonic, but when LC  contains complicated custom logic within it another LC with if statements  ( or has long logic statements) it's better to write for loop with list comprehension.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko: this is not the case here, it is simply a *nested* `for` loop, not a nested list comprehension.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem don't mind for that case. But it's very easy to get 'in love' with LC and start to write non-readable code....

Comment: The idea that LCs are more Pythonic than a for-loop is dubious. Both constructs are fine. Now, a `while` loop would definitely not be Pythonic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. One followup question is How to do conditional checking in the list comprehensions? For example, if want to conditionally filter the duplicate elements in the returned list, it would be easy in doing the second way. But how to do that in list comprehension method?

Comment: I would prefer the second, since it looks clearer to me.